# Select the first two character in SQL Server CE

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

**[ANSWER]**

Thanks everyone! The code to solved the problem below is:

```
SELECT ID
FROM Schedule
WHERE (SUBSTRING(Time, 1, 2) = DATEPART(hh, GETDATE()))
```

---

How to select the first two character in SQL Server CE?

For example:

```
+-----+-----------+------------+
+ Day +  Time     +  ID        +
+-----+-----------+------------+
+ 1   +  08:00:00 +  A1        +
+ 1   +  09:00:00 +  A2        +
+ 1   +  09:30:00 +  A3        +
+ 1   +  10:15:00 +  A4        + 
+-----+-----------+------------+
```

`Time` column is a `nvarchar` type.

Then, I want to select the `ID` only with the time based on the real-hour, like only select the `08` part from `08:00:00`. How can I do that?

Comment: Your Time column shouldn't be a VARCHAR type; it should be a TIME type.

Comment: What database engine?  MSFT, Oracle, DB2, all use different methods for this.

Comment: Please remember to identify both the SQL DBMS you are using and the name of your table (if only so that the answers can all use the same name -- it can be a name made up for the purposes of the question).

Comment: The answer is entirely product dependent (there is a standard, but many databases don't implement it).  Please specify what dialect of SQL you're using.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SUBSTRING is available in CE - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa275646(SQL.80).aspx

```
SUBSTRING ( expression , start , length )
```

Answer (score 2):

The SQL Standard method is given by the syntax diagram:

```
<character substring function> ::=
         SUBSTRING <left paren> <character value expression> FROM <start position>
         [ FOR <string length> ] [ USING <char length units> ] <right paren>
```

Hence, in this example:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Time FROM 1 FOR 2) FROM AnonymousTable;
```

Some DBMS (Oracle, and those emulating Oracle) provide a SUBSTR() function instead:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Time, 1, 2) FROM AnonymousTable;
```

The `1` is the starting offset, counting from 1, and the `2` is the length (not the finishing offset, though they are the same for this example, and any other where the start is 1).

There may be other methods for your particular DBMS.  For example, with Informix you could write:

```
SELECT Time[1,2] FROM AnonymousTable;
```

This time though, the subscripts are start and stop positions.

Informix supports all three of these.  I don't know of any other DBMS that uses the subscript notation.

Comment: It couldn't work. It returns: `The function is not recognized by SQL Server Compact. [Name of function = SUBSTR, Data type (if known) = ]`

Comment: OK - now you know why it is important to specify your DBMS up front.

Comment: @mrjimoy_05: Thank you for accepting my answer, but the 'accept' belongs to [Chris Gessler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491251/select-the-first-two-character-in-sql-ce/10491335#10491335) because he gives you the syntax you need for SQL Server, whereas mine is a more general answer.  Please unaccept this answer and accept his answer instead. (I'll happily accept an up-vote if you've not already given me one, though.) Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry. Because I think because your answer are given a detail explanation about the problem, so I choose to accept your answer. But, thank you for the suggestion. :)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like this?

```
SELECT LEFT(Time, 2) From Table
```

Comment: Exactly. But it couldn't work. It returns: `The function is not recognized by SQL Server Compact. [Name of function = SUBSTR, Data type (if known) = ]`